# What's the value of having fn's name name on both sides of assignment operator (an object fn)?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Example:

```
(function () {
    object.module('something').objectMethod('someController', [
        '$param1', 'param2', function (paramY, paramE) {
            $param1.someScopedVariable = function() {
                laa-dee-dah();
            }

            // VS.

            $param1.someOtherScopedVariable = function someOtherScopedVariable {

            }
        }
    ]);
})());
```

What's the difference?

Comment: names are a lot easier to debug than staring at 342 "anonymous" entries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is an anonymous function expression. The second is a [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression). One reason you might want to use a named function expression is to easily create recursive functions (functions that call themselves). An example is the factorial function in that link.